# Updating Table in SQL Server via xlsx/CSV upload

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have created a table in my SQL Server by uploading an Excel file.

This is a table that will have to be updated every month manually.

The way I have done this is by going to tasks->import data and choose Microsoft Excel as the source, and then I select one of the existing tables in my database as the destination.

When I re-upload the xlsx file with updated values to the same table, the values don't update on the table in our server.

Can someone advise how to update an existing table in SQL Server via CSV/xlsx upload?

Comment: CSV and XLS are very different formats. CSV is a text file (that can be exported from excel). CSV is far simpler to import into SQL Server than XLS. The important question is: do you simply want to completely replace the existing table data with whatever is in your import file?

Comment: Hi, yes correct, I would like to replace the existing table data based on my import file

Comment: If I was doing this, I would create a batch file that uses `SQLCMD.EXE` to truncate the table then `BCP.EXE` to import the CSV file. If you don't want to use that method you can also do it manually by 1. Log into the database, run `DROP TABLE xyz` to remove the table 2. Use the SSMS menu to import the flat file (CSV) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks I'll give the first method a go

Comment: if you're importing through the import data wizard, there's an option to drop table before creating it again, so you can do that, or alternatively delete stuff before importing